# Why is it impossible to implement an "infinite" one time pad algorithm?

Tags: encryption, encryption-symmetric

I've done some research into this, but I'm still not sure why this cannot be implemented. Provided we share an initial OTP, possibly via USB or some other physically secure method, surely we can include the next one in the messages that follow.

[Edit: More specifically, if I were to take a pad of double length, splitting it into x and y. Then using x to encrypt the message, and using y twice to encrypt the next pad, would that be insecure?]

Comment: This isn't really about programming, but rather about devising a secure One-Time Pad protocol *and* analysing the security of the suggested design. [crypto.se] is much better suited for questions like this.

Comment: Thanks @ArtjomB., I will ask it there.

Comment: Cross-posting is frowned upon. You should change the question to properly match the community (only ask for security assessment of your suggested protocol) if you really want to do this. Otherwise, you should flag for moderator attention asking to migrate this question.

Comment: I will specify for this particular protocol then. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to pair each bit of message with a same size bit of OTP. There's a limited amount of OTP.

If you pair up all of the OTP bits with bits for the next OTP...

```
a b c d e ...
q w e r t ...
```

There's no room for a message. And if you keep spending your OTP transferring another OTP, there never will be room for a message.

You can't compress the OTP, because the strength of the OTP is that it's completely random - that's what makes it impossible for codebreakers, because there's no pattern to latch onto.

Compression is a technology that works by finding patterns and replacing them with shorter "that large repetitive block goes here and here and there" signals - and by definition there are no patterns in complete randomness, so OTPs are not compressible.

If you can compress it a bit, you could do this but it's not right to describe it as OTP anymore, it's weak - and also massively wasteful of bandwidth. If you can compress it a lot, throw your random number generator away it's terrible.

---

Quick test demonstration of concept on a linux machine:

```
$ dd if=/dev/urandom of=/tmp/test count=10k
    -> 5Mb file of randomness

$ bzip2 /tmp/test 
    -> 5.1Mb file
$ gzip /tmp/test
    -> 5.1Mb file
```

Compressing a pad makes it bigger, by adding all the bzip/gzip file format information and doing nothing else.

Comment: So, if I were to take a pad of double length, splitting it into x and y. Then using x to encrypt the message, and using y twice to encrypt the next pad, would that be insecure? [I have edited the original question to include this.]

Comment: @user2387653 I'm not a cryptographer, but I believe a truly random OTP is literally unbreakable - there is nothing that could ever be invented that could crack it just by looking at the coded message. As soon as any pattern is introduced, e.g. repeating some of it, then it is weakened. Changing infinitely strong to finitely strong - is that *infinitely weaker*? I have no idea how crackable a system that repeats half the pad might be - easy or still difficult, I can't guess. I don't know how it would compare to AES128 or common ciphers. But: it's no longer a *One Time* Pad, then.

Comment: @TesselatingHeckler, thanks for your answer. As ArtjomB. suggested above I will ask this on the cryptography stack exchange.

Answer (score 0):

What makes a One-Time Pad strong is, in addition to the lack of a pattern, the fact that there is no way to tell that the key used was the correct key. A message could be decrypted to reveal some "take over the world" scenario, but literally every message encrypted with a key of that exact length has a key that reveals that exact same message, word for word. This means you could have the actual decrypted message and the correct key, but it would be impossible to know that this is the case, and because literally any message (and I do mean literally) of that length can be a result. Even rubber-hose-decryption won't work. Even if the person being "persuaded" gives the correct key, there's no way to be sure. It's even common practice for people to possess fake keys that decrypt messages to reveal a message that isn't what an investigator is looking for, but would definitely be something even a completely innocent person would hide. A OTP hiding confidential information could, for instance, have a fake key that reveals someone bad-mouthing their commanding officer.

Comment: Every key has the property that "there is no way to tell that the key used was the correct key" without having some knowledge about the plain text contents, this is commonly called a "crib". This is why good encryption includes an authentication MAC. The technical term is ["Rubber-Hose Cryptanalysis"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber-hose_cryptanalysis) See also [Schneier on Security](https://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2008/10/rubber_hose_cry.html) and of course [xkcd](http://xkcd.com/538/).

Comment: What makes  One-Time Pad strong is that it is used only once, is as random as possible and is the same length as the message.